# I need help identifying this quadricolor waxy leafed plant

Tags: houseplants

I rescued this plant from a retail store years ago. It became homeless when the display it in was used for was replaced with something new.

It's gotten ridiculously large and has always been wonderfully healthy 
and I just love it.

Unfortunately it's gotten a wee bit sick recently and I need to identify what it is so I can try to figure out what's wrong.

Any Ideas? [image: Waxy Quadricolor plant]

Answer (score 2):

It is a variegated Ficus elastica; the pot is not visible in the photo, so it's hard to say whether it needs a larger one or not. These plants get pretty tall and treelike, so potting into larger pots every couple of years is often necessary. What can be seen of the plant appears mostly healthy - they like relatively high levels of daylight, but not direct sun (especially during summer) and yours is obviously next to a window; because its healthy, it's clearly largely happy with its environment, but possibly, if it has been exposed to sun, that might explain the brownish grey dead areas. Otherwise, check beneath the leaves and all the stems for signs of any type of insect infestation. Further information on care as a houseplant here https://www.joyusgarden.com/rubber-plant-growing-tips/